# .htaccess keeps deleting a line and throwing 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

my website keep getting the 404 error and I don't know what's causing it but I narrowed it down to the .htaccess document.
here is the bad .htdaccess  doc

```
AuthType ****
AuthName "******"
AuthUserFile /******/****
Require user *******
```

and this the working doc

```
AuthType ****
AuthName "******"
AuthUserFile /******/****
Require user ******
DirectoryIndex *******
```

I don't know what keeps deleting the "DirectoryIndex *******" line. I know it's not me.

any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: What kind of site is this? Static? Hand coded? Using a CMS? Are you using an unusual directory index document?

Comment: its static I have to add everything by hand but users can download.

Comment: There is _something missing_ here... on a hand coded / static site there's nothing that should be "deleting" that line (or recovering the previous version) - unless perhaps the file is not actually being overwritten when you upload it? Although I assume when you upload that file, it does appear to correct the problem for a period of time? Also, I don't see how the inclusion of that directive would resolve a 404? If the `DirectoryIndex` was set incorrectly (or perhaps omitted) and directory indexes were not enabled then you'd expect a 403 Forbidden, not a 404 Not Found?